# Edit/revise option for authors to suggest improvement to posts

Tags: plugins, posts, moderation, multi-author

I have a multiple author blog with 300 authors. Is it possible to add a edit type of button where authors can suggest improvement to other authors published articles? If an improvement suggesting is added, the entry should only be visible to users with author permission and the original author of the article can make the decision of implementing the edit.

This feature would be highly beneficial for content heavy sites. Do anyone knows if such plugin is available? Or an alternative solution?

Comment: This is quite a good idea but it won't be easy... at least I don't think it will be. I will think about it.

Comment: [This thread may help.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71549/is-there-a-plugin-to-allow-anonymous-users-to-suggests-edits-for-a-post)

Comment: Unfortunately in this form it's overly broad and plugin recommendations have been made off topic. Is it possible to implement? Yep, but it's way beyond what can fit in question/answer format.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Edit Flow](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/edit-flow/) plugin to allow authors to leave meta comments only visible in the backend or however you choose to display them on the frontend.

Comment: I already use that plugin :) However, I am looking for a full on edit system like what stackoverflow has. This new plugin named Fork seems interesting though...